# Setting stack size with setrlimit fails with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, stack, g++, clang++

I'm using gcc 10.1 on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm getting segfaults when defining a large stack allocated variable, even though my stack seems to be large enough to accommodate it. Here is a code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <sys/resource.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  if (struct rlimit rl{1<<28, 1l<<32}; setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl))
    cout << "Can not set stack size! errno = " << errno << endl;
  else
    cout << "Stack size: " << rl.rlim_cur/(1<<20) << "MiB to " << rl.rlim_max/(1<<20) << "MiB\n";

  array<int8_t, 100'000'000> a;

  cout << (int)a[42] << endl;
}
```

which segfaults when compiled with gcc, but runs fine when compiled with clang 11.0.1 and outputs:

```
Stack size: 256MiB to 4096MiB
0
```

**EDIT**

Clang was eliding allocation of `a`. Here is a better example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <sys/resource.h>

using namespace std;

void f() {
  array<int8_t, 100'000'000> a;

  cout << (long)&a[0] << endl;    
}

int main()
{
  if (struct rlimit rl{1<<28, 1l<<32}; setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl))
    cout << "Can not set stack size! errno = " << errno << endl;
  else
    cout << "Stack size: " << rl.rlim_cur/(1<<20) << "MiB to " << rl.rlim_max/(1<<20) << "MiB" << endl;

  array<int8_t, 100'000'000> a; // line 21

  cout << (long)&a[0] << endl;  // line 23
  f();
}
```

which you can find at: https://wandbox.org/permlink/XMaGFMa7heWfI9G8. It runs fine when lines 21 and 23 are commented out, but segfaults otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) and [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the limitations of your computer.

```
array<int8_t, 100'000'000> a;
```

requires about 100Mbytes of space on [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), which is generally limited to a few megabytes (perhaps even by your Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/), but I am not sure)

Try also `cat /proc/$$/limits` in your terminal. On mine I am getting

```
 Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
 Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
 Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
 Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
 Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
```

The difference of behavior between compilers might be attributed to various optimizations (e.g. permitted by some C++ standard like [n4849](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf)). A clever enough compiler is allowed to use just a few words for `a` inside your function `f` (e.g. because it would figure out, maybe with some [abstract interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation) techniques, that locations `a[1024]` ... `a[99999999]` are useless).

If you compile with a *recent* [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (e.g. [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/)), you could [invoke it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) as `g++ -O -Wall -Wextra -fanalyzer -Wstack-usage=2048` to get useful warnings. See also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report funded by [CHARIOT](http://chariotproject.eu/) & [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) projects.

In practice, use dynamic allocation for huge data (e.g. [placement `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) with [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory))

For a real application, consider writing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to get ad-hoc warnings.

Or at least compile your source code `foo.cc` with `g++ -O2 -fverbose-asm -S foo.cc` and look inside the generated `foo.s` and repeat with `clang++` : the generated assembler files are different.

Comment: My computer has 32GB RAM, so there is no practical limitation for 256MB stack. Are you saying that maximum stack size is limited by Linux and can't be changed by calling `setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, ...)`?

Comment: IIRC, the maximal stack size might be limited by the Linux kernel. Consider recompiling it.

Comment: Thanks. That would explain sparcity of information about setting stack size on Linux. I was bulding my application with 256MB stack on Windows with no problems. I'm surprised that `setrlimit` is misleading in this case.

Comment: I tested the super smart optimizer theory and it doesn't hold. See: https://wandbox.org/permlink/D1nK7zM5zjPHTZF6, where large `a` in function `f` is just fine, but segfaults in `main`.

Comment: What makes you believe that your process has a large call stack?

Comment: I'm assuming that `a` is stack allocated and there is no way for the compiler to elide the allocation inside `f`.

Comment: The generated assembler code is different with clang and with GCC.

Comment: Maybe this will be a more convincing example, where large `a` can't be optimized out: https://wandbox.org/permlink/HJW3jeiXbG4F2onl